# How to simplify query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller method for searching and listing invoices, sales orders and homes based on params name, how to simplify this index method`

```
def index
      @so = QbwcSalesOrder.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
      if params[:qs] == "Sales Orders"
        @so = @so.where("ref_number = ? ",params[:keyword]) if params[:keyword].present?
   elsif params[:qs] == "Invoices" 
        @so = QbwcInvoice.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
        @so = @so.where("ref_number = ? ",params[:keyword])  if params[:keyword].present?
   elsif params[:qs] == "All Homes" 
        @so = QbwcHome.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
   elsif params[:qs] == "Existing Homes" 
        @so = QbwcHome.where(record_type: "FromQB").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all unify hash syntax and indentation, it's hard to read.

Second paginate once at the end of the index method, looks like you paginate always the same way.

Third think about scopes or query object https://mkdev.me/en/posts/how-to-use-query-objects-to-refactor-rails-sql-queries

Here is simplified version, you can use it in index or move to the query object:

```rb
def index
  @so = QbwcSalesOrder.all

  @so = @so.where("ref_number = ? ", params[:keyword]) if params[:keyword] && params[:qs] == "Sales Orders"
  @so = @so.where("ref_number = ? ", params[:keyword]) if params[:keyword] && params[:qs] == "Invoices"
  @so = @so.where(record_type: "FromQB") if params[:qs] == "Existing Homes" 
  @so = @so if params[:qs] == "All Homes" 

  @so = @so.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
end
```

Comment: @tolarz I am trying to filter '@so' from different tables.

Comment: missed that, so you can use names of the tables instead of `@so`

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the logic into separate methods. As already mentioned in another answer it makes sense to move it to a query object or something.

```rb
def index
  scope = invoices || all_homes || existing_homes || sales_orders
  @so = scope.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
end

private

def invoices
  return if params[:qs] != 'Invoices'
  return QbwcInvoice if params[:keyword].blank?
  QbwcInvoice.where(ref_number: params[:keyword])
end

def all_homes
  QbwcHome if params[:qs] == 'All Homes'
end

def existing_homes
  QbwcHome.where(record_type: 'FromQB') if params[:qs] == 'Existing Homes'
end

def sales_orders
  if params[:qs] == 'Sales Orders' && params[:keyword].present?
    QbwcSalesOrder.where(ref_number: params[:keyword])
  else
    QbwcSalesOrder
  end
end
```

Comment: The devil is in the details - if you look carefully there are three different models involved: QbwcSalesOrder, QbwcInvoice and QbwcHome.

Comment: @Yakov ,This will work if I am trying to filter results from same table. But I am trying to filter from different tables

Comment: That's true, I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: As @max mentioned it would be good to not rely on human-readable values.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like the method is doing way to much and needs to be split into managable parts:

```
def index
  @so = qs_model_scope(params[:qs])
          .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
          .then do |scope|
            filter_by_keyword(scope)
          end
end

# ...

private

def qs_model_scope(qs)
  case qs
  when "Invoices":
    QbwcInvoice.all
  when "All Homes":
    # Smelly - should be a model scope
    QbwcHome.where(record_type: "FromQB")
  else
    QbwcSalesOrder.all
  end
end 

def filter_by_keyword(scope)
  if params[:keyword].present? && ["QbwcSalesOrder","QbwcInvoice"].include?(scope.model.name)
    # no need to use a SQL string
    scope.where(ref_number: params[:keyword])   
  else
    scope
  end
end
```

If the complexity of this continues to grow you should consider moving this filtering process out of the controller and into a separate object (such as a form object or service object or just a PORO) so that it can be tested in isolation.

Comment: One thing that still irks me with this code is that you're passing `"All Homes"` and `"Invoices"` as values from the form instead of something more "machine readable". That means that when you have to change or localize the option texts you'll break your backend code.